# iphone facebook session failing. why?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm learning how to integrate facebook api in iphone app.
First I visited facebook website, went to applications->developer and created an app. Noted down private key and secret key.
Now, I'm using FBConnect sample code. I am using my keys in FBConnect app. And I set session proxy as

```
static NSString* kGetSessionProxy = @"SessionViewController"; // @"<YOUR SESSION CALLBACK)>";
```

I'm able to run the app and when I click "Connect to Facebook", its asking me for credentials as well. But afte providing credentials, its failing. The following delegate method is being called:

```
- (void)sessionDidNotLogin:(FBSession*)session { _label.text = @"Canceled login"; }
```

I'm not understanding why I'm ending up in above delegate.

What are all options that I've to select in facebook website when creating new application?

Please help me.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough info about the error. The FBSession object should provide more details. You should log it to see what it reports and then edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I made kGetSessionProxy to nil, it worked without any problem. But I didn't understand why it didn't when i gave some value.